# Is there a way to add variable to jquery css method?

Tags: jquery, html, css

is there any way to replace 255px from code below with variable width?

```
var width = $(".input-textbox").width();

     $("#txtTryContactMob").css('background', '#fff url(\"/img/erroricon.png\") 255px center no-repeat');
```

I have read a little about it and I don't want to use LESS css.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'#fff url(\"/img/erroricon.png\") '+width+'px center no-repeat'`? Have you tried string concatenation?

Comment: Yes but a different way :) looks like I made a mistake, will try your solution.

Comment: Note: You did not need to escape the double-quotes inside a single-quoted string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also separate the width from the rest of the CSS style by specifically targetting just the `background-size` style:

```
 var width = $(".input-textbox").width();
 $("#txtTryContactMob").css('background', '#fff url("/img/erroricon.png") 255px center no-repeat')
      .css('background-size', width);
```

**Notes:**

- it does not need the `px` added when using a single CSS property.
- You did not need to escape the double-quotes inside a single-quoted string

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this by simple concatenation

```
var customwidth = $(".input-textbox").width();
     $("#txtTryContactMob").css('background', '#fff url(\"/img/erroricon.png\") '+customwidth+'px center no-repeat');
```

Answer (score 1):

To reply your question, "***How to add variable to jquery css method?***", maybe hash format `css` looks more expandable:

```
$("#txtTryContactMob").css({
  "background": '#fff url("/img/erroricon.png") center',
  "background-size": $(".input-textbox").width() + "px",
  "background-repeat": "no-repeat",
  "background-position": "center"
  // more attribute pairs
});
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp for more `background` details.